# Xamarin Cross Platform App without a Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

Do I still need a Mac to build a Xamarin cross platform app? I'm on Windows 10 running Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

I read a while ago that with iOS Simulator, I could build a cross platform app using Xamarin. I also read that iOS Simulator requires Visual Studio Enterprise.

I can update my Visual Studio to Enterprise but I want to make sure I can indeed build a Xamarin cross platform app in Visual Studio 2017 without needing a Mac.

Comment: Last time i built with 2017.3.3 It required a mac. If it's possible in any way i would imagine they work on it, unless apple strong arms them into not doing it so they can sell more macs.

Comment: You already asked this question - the answer hasn't changed.  All of the iOS build tools are provided by Apple and will only run on a Mac.  Xamarin does have a new tool "Xamarin Live Player" that allows you to debug on a device without the need for a Mac, but you cannot build an app for distribution without a Mac.